# django/python: Google doc viewer issue with .docx/.xlsx/.pptx

Tags: python, django, google-docs

We are using google doc viewer to view ms-office files

Issue: When we try to view it through Viewer it open the document saying PK

When I searched for the issue I got a helpful link: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/documents/7j_BXBtQWQg

It says that:Content-Type header sent by your server is incorrect

How can we change/correct Content-Type header send by server in django/python ??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you serve the file dynamically (ie; rather than using a standard staticfile), you could return an HttpResponse with the contents of the file and then set your own content-type. I've done this with images before:

```
return HttpResonse(the_file, "Content-Type: image/png")
```

Where the_file is the actual file data (not the file object).

Would that work for your purposes?

Comment: Are you sure with above, what you tried for images.. Because I tried it, but it didn't worked out.. until I provided the viewer the actual static path of my files..